# adding a facebook Like IMAGE to site (but keeping with FB TOS/Platform Policy)

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-like, facebook-social-plugins

I would like to have a facebook looking image (just like the one on this page to the left of the post).  That image should be clicked to be able to "Like" the given page.

How do I do that?  (and do it according to Facebook's TOS / Platform Policy?)

Thank you!

Comment: You know, like Twitter Intents....

Comment: @RandolphWest - YES.  I have been scouring the documentation, and I can't seem to find what I am looking for.  I always do research before posting, and this research is bordering on several hours now.  Thanks for the concern.  What I really need right now are solutions, if you have them, please.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want a [Share button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/) rather than a like button?

Keeping in mind that this has been deprecated in favor of the like button, just create your share URL and link to it

```
http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<url to share>&t=<title of content>
```

Comment: This is really really close to what I want.  Is there a non-deprecated solution?

Comment: PS, thank you for being helpful when everyone else simply wants to point out the obvious and go downvote crazy!  (Upvote).

Comment: Mr A typicly this forum of Q&A is geared for more technical questions, i think most readers seen this as a legal question.

Comment: @ShawnECarter - thanks for the explanation.  Although, I'm interested in the technical answers *within* the legal framework.  I tried posting this before and got downvoted because I was trying to do something against TOS, so I reposted to make it clear that I want the technical answer but legally.  I hope it's clear I'm not looking for a "can I do this?" but more of a "How do I do this, but legally?"....   

PS, thanks again

Comment: Oh wait - I want this to *look* like the Share button, but I do want it to "Like" my page.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You need to refer to the Brand Resource Center on Facebook about usage https://www.facebook.com/brandpermissions/logos.php

Comment: It says I can do it.  Now... how?

Comment: read carefully, you can not use the actual like button image you can download the provided and use as facebook shows you in the examples.

Comment: So how is stackoverflow doing it?